# Javascript Promise With Once And On

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to implement Promise with `once` and `on`.

Operation flow is like this:
[image]

Promise will start once txn is started:

- once **txn_id** is generated

```
promise.once('idCreated', (txnId) => console.log)
```

- promise will also return how much estimate time is left

```
promise.on('timeLeft', (seconds) => console.log)
```

**resolve** and **reject** are for txn done and failed respectively.

Can anyone please explain, how exactly I can use Promise with EventEmitter or do something like this

Below is a popular JS library:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/callbacks-promises-events.html

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x123...', data: '0x432...'})
.once('transactionHash', function(hash){ ... })
.once('receipt', function(receipt){ ... })
.on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.then(function(receipt){
    // will be fired once the receipt is mined
});
```

I want to acheive same result but not sure where to start

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code.  You can't just slam EventEmitter methods onto a promise and expect them to work.  Those EventEmitter methods need an EventEmitter instance at their core in order to work.  In addition, promises are ONE-SHOT devices.  They resolve or reject exactly once and never change their state after that.  As such, they are a bad match for any event that can occur more than once.  This really needs a different design.  I can't really tell what the actual problem to be solved is here to know exactly what to suggest.

Comment: I'm alreday instantiating it on top... secondly I saw `on` and `once` with PROMISE widely used in many libraries.. Also the question I tag at bottom have this kind of feature

Comment: You try to use `promise.once()`, but there's NO eventEmitter instance in the promise.  That won't work.  Plus, you pass `.once()` an event name and a callback function, not an event name and an object.  Like I said, lots wrong here.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you please write code snippet as answer... it would be really helpful

Comment: Like I said earlier, I don't understand your problem well enough to know what to suggest.  An eventEmitter and a promise should not be put into the same object.  They are oil and water.  I don't see how that referenced answer where you got this code from could work at all.  If you have some existing event-driven object, you can create a separate promise that monitors certain one-time events on that event-driven object, but you don't try to cram the two objects into the same promise.

Comment: Please go back to square one and describe what problem you are trying to solve and show REAL code that runs and describe something you want help with on that code.  So far, this is a theoretical design question with an unclear problem statement and with no running code that works so it's really hard for us to know what to answer.

Comment: FYI, for a lot of reasons, it's generally a bad idea to try to add custom methods to a promise instance.  Besides losing performance optimizations from an optimizing compiler, chaining a promise (a typical way of using a promise) creates a new promise that won't have the new stuff on it, messing things up.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just updated question... I also add ref to a popular JS library maybe you can understand what exactly they are doing

Comment: FYI, building one of those promi-event things that the web3js library shows is not a trivial thing to do correctly.  I looked through part of that library's code and it's a maze - was not able to find where they build those objects in a reasonable amount of time.  If you want to learn more about how they do it, I'd suggest you study their code yourself.  I probably would not implement things that way myself.

Comment: @jfriend00 "*You can't just slam EventEmitter methods onto a promise and expect them to work*" - actually `EventEmitter` is a mixin, so it would be possible in theory. But I very much agree that it shouldn't be done here.

Comment: *"I'm trying to implement..."*: if you have a question about that attempt, it may help to actually include it.

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, I know you can basically do anything in Javascript (mix any objects you want).  But, without a better understanding of the real underlying problem, I don't have enough info to know this is actually the preferred way to solve some problem.  You could certainly subclass an EventEmitter, add a promise to the instance data, proxy `.then()`, `.catch()` and `.finally()` to that promise and have a combined object.  The question here is why go to that trouble?